# Is this a valid way to use Blocks in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I've been building an HTTP client that uses web services to synchronize information between the client and server.  I've been using Blocks and NSURLConnection to achieve this on the client side, but I'm getting frequent EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes in objc_msgSend(). From what I understand, this usually means that a stored block that has fallen off the stack has been called. I think I've coded things correctly to avoid this, but I'm still stuck.

Here is what my code is doing conceptually. It starts by calling "synchronizeWithWebServer". That method invokes "listRootObjectsOnServerWithBlock:" which takes in a block to be called when the method returns.

"listRootObjectsOnServersWithBlock:" initiates a NSURLConnection to the web server asynchronously.  It expects a block to be called when it returns. Inside that block I want to be able to execute the original Block (so aptly named 'block').

This is only a simplified version of my code. The real synchronization process is more complex but it's mostly more of the same as what you see below.

Sometimes the code works perfectly, but about 80% of the time it crashes very early on in the routine.  It seems to be more vulnerable to crashing when my data set gets larger.

```
  - (void)synchronizeWithWebServer
  {
       [self listRootObjectsOnServerWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

           //Iterate over result objects and perform some other similar routines.
       }];
  }

  - (void)listRootObjectsOnServerWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *results, NSError *error))block
  {
       //Create NSURLRequest Here

       //Create connection asynchronously.
       block = [block copy];
       [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest 
                                          queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                              completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){

                       //Parse response from web server (stored in NSData *data)
                       NSArray *results = .....

                       //Call 'block'
                       block(results, error);
                       [block release];
                       }];
   }
```

Comment: try setting up NSZombies and see which deallocated object is sent a message.

Comment: By golly I think you are on to something with that.  Why didn't I think to do that?  Let me take some time to look at it now.

Comment: Wow - That was it.  It turns out I was using the blocks correctly, but i was just over-releasing a stupid NSDictionary.  Can't thank you enough.

Comment: feel free to post it as an answer so that you can mark the question as closed.

Comment: Thanks to MCannon for the assistance. I profiled my application in Instruments and quickly found a zombie.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to use the `Build & Analyze` tool of Xcode. This might have been able to find the issue, too.

Comment: Obviously this wasn't the problem (since you've already found the problem), but you should move the `[block release]` to after the NSURLConnection call, not in the completion handler. The completion handler will automatically retain the block when it is created, so you can release it after that. This will prevent problems if, for some reason, the completion handler gets called twice.

Comment: In fact, you don't need to copy the block at all. The -sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: method will copy the completion handler, which will recursively copy your block. It will also release it automatically.

Comment: @kperryua i haven't tested this exact case, but as far as i've read, it automatically RETAINS the block, which isn't enough for a stack allocated block. There has to be one copy to move the block to the heap, after wich retain release should work

Comment: Execute "print (char *)$rsi" in debugger when crash occurs. Make sure selected frame is objc_msgSend().